# Is schema definition compulsory for WFS-T

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs-t

Most tutorials on WFS transaction uses a schema and geom attributes in WFS request like this

```
var wfs_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
//projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:26910"),
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
version: "1.1.0",
url: "http://localhost/geoserver/wfs",
featureNS :  "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
featureType: "wfst_test",
**geometryName: "the_geom",**
**schema: "http://localhost/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&;typename=cite:wfst_test"**
})
});
```

can we omit this or is it compulsory to include them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are posting a XML document inside insert transactions it should be compulsory to also provide a schema for it. Some servers might accept the transaction even without the schema.

Comment: does geoserver require schema definition?

Comment: As far as I know it does not, provided you specify the right namespace for the feature you are inserting

Comment: the namespace is correct, the feature id gets inserted but the geometry does not. what might have happened?

Comment: Often this happens because the geometry is encoded in the wrong version of GML, e.g., GML 2 but you are inserting in a WFS 1.1 transaction that requires GML 3. Another possibility is a geometry type mismatch, you are trying to insert a point in a table that only accepts polygons

Comment: I am using Openlayers.handler.path to draw linear feature, and the geom type of feature is multiline string. i have also cast the line to multiline using this code      __draw.featureAdded = function(feature) {
   feature.layer.eraseFeatures([feature]);
   // cast to multilinestring
   feature.geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiLineString(feature.geometry);
   //alert(feature.geometry);
   //feature.style.strokeColor = "#ff0000";
   feature.state = OpenLayers.State.INSERT;
   feature.layer.drawFeature(feature);
  }__